# Is "Reishit Ketzir" a holiday, half-holiday, regular day, or else?

Tags: halacha, passover, korban, maaser-tithes, nissan

In [Leviticus 23:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.23.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), one encounters the term "Reishit Ketzirchem" (i.e. "Reishit Ketzir" = Beginning of Harvest). "Thus, one is permitted to proceed with the general harvest only after this omer has been reaped" [Sifthei Chachamim; Men. 71a], so quoted in Rashi.

What do the rabbis say about "*Reishit Ketzir*" (Beginning of Harvest)?

Namely:

- Is it a holiday/chag, half-holiday, regular day, chol-moed, etc.?
- Is it a part of Chag Pesach or of Chag Matzot or a stand-alone chag?

I would like to know if I am reading this correctly. Is it not written in Menachot.10 (for example) that ראשית קציר ([Leviticus 23:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.23.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) was reaped by just one person on shabbat ("אֶחָד בְּשַׁבָּת וְאֶחָד בְּחֹל" Menachot.10), best occuring on the **night** of Nisan 16 ("מִצְוָתוֹ לִקְצֹר בַּלַּיְלָה" Menachot.10) and יום הנף took place on the **morning** of Nisan 16; and by **afternoon** of Nisan 16, the markets are full of harvest ("מִשֶּׁקָּרַב הָעֹמֶר, יוֹצְאִין וּמוֹצְאִין שׁוּק יְרוּשָׁלַיִם שֶׁהוּא מָלֵא קֶמַח וְקָלִי" Menachot.10)?

**Additionally** (if it helps):

Another phrase that has the word "Ketzir" is "Bikurey Ketzir" בכורי קציר , which is also known as "Chag Shavuoth" חג השבועות in [Numbers 28:26](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.28.26?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). This is a commentary in Rashi:

> וביום הבכורים: חג השבועות קרוי בכורי קציר חטים על שם שתי הלחם, שהם ראשונים למנחת חטים הבאים מן החדש: — [Menachos 84b]

My conclusion is:
If "Bikurey Ketzir" בכורי קציר (which occurs during Chag Shavuoth) is "Chag Shavuoth" (Numbers 28:26), then "Reishit Ketzir" ראשית קציר (which occurs during Chag Matzot) is "Chag Matzot" (Leviticus 23:6).

Comment: Not clear on what you’re asking (and the tags don’t help, since this doesn’t seem to be at all related to Shavuos, Bikkurim, Maaser, or Sefer Bamidbar). Are you asking A) when the harvest took place, and B) if it was considered a holiday, and if so, why harvesting was permitted? This was flagged as unclear, but if that is what you’re asking, I’d recommend splitting this into two questions to prevent a “too broad” closure.

Comment: @DonielF my main question is: Is reishit ketzir a holiday, half-holiday, regular day? Is it a part of Chag Pesach or of Chag Matzot or a stand-alone chag?

Comment: @DonielF I have narrowed my post, as per your comment.

Comment: @Al_Berko, thanks for the helpful edit. By editing it so, do you concur that "Reishit Ketzir" took place on a particular day, that perhaps ראשית קציר (Leviticus 23:10) was reaped by just one person on shabbat ("אֶחָד בְּשַׁבָּת וְאֶחָד בְּחֹל" Menachot.10), best occuring on the NIGHT of Nisan 16 ("מִצְוָתוֹ לִקְצֹר בַּלַּיְלָה" Menachot.10) and יום הנף took place on the MORNING of Nisan 16; and by AFTERNOON of Nisan 16, the markets are full of harvest ("מִשֶּׁקָּרַב הָעֹמֶר, יוֹצְאִין וּמוֹצְאִין שׁוּק יְרוּשָׁלַיִם שֶׁהוּא מָלֵא קֶמַח וְקָלִי" Menachot.10)?

Comment: That’s exactly right, except that it’s not “best” occurring on the night of the 16th - it has to be on the night of the 16th.

Comment: @DonielF The word "best" occurs in the explainer translation of the Mishnah_Menochot; the exact English quote in Mishnah_Menachot_10 reads "The best fulfillment of] its commandment is that it be reaped at night".

Comment: I stand corrected - the Mishnah itself says that quite clearly, נקצר ביום כשר.

Comment: @DonielF Is ראשית קציר therefore a part of Chag Pesach or of Chag Matzot or a stand-alone chag; or none of these, if so, what?

Answer (score 1):

When I look at the translations of Lev 23 (10) I get no impression that there is a day referred to as Reishis Ketzir.

See [Chabad](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9924#showrashi=true)

> Speak to the children of Israel and say to them: When you come to the
>   Land which I am giving you, and you reap its harvest, you shall bring
>   to the kohen an omer of **the beginning of your reaping.**

And [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Leviticus.23.10?lang=bi&aliyot=0)

> Speak to the Israelite people and say to them: When you enter the land
>   that I am giving to you and you reap its harvest, you shall bring the
>   **first** sheaf **of your harvest** to the priest.

So Reishis Ketzir is not a day and the Rabbis have nothing to say about it as a day.

The procedure of cutting the omer is explained in [Mishna Menochos 10 (3)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Menachot.10?lang=bi).

ADDITION

Sources show that it was permitted to begin eating the harvest of new grain in the times of the Beis Hamikdosh after the waving of the omer offering. Also it is clear that after the destruction of the Beis Hamikdosh, Rabban Yoḥanan ben Zakkai instituted that for the entire day of waving the omer offering, i.e., the sixteenth of Nisan, eating the grain of the new crop is prohibited.

You might infer from the above paragraph that the harvest started before the omer was brought. So I see that the Yom Honaif was not the beginning of the harvest. This inference is maintained from the mishna in [Menachos 10 (5)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Menachot.10.5?lang=bi&with=Bartenura&lang2=en) where you see that

> Once the omer was offered, they used to go out and find the market of
>   Jerusalem already full of flour and parched grain [of the new
>   produce], [though this was] against the will of the Sages, [these are]
>   the words of Rabbi Meir; Rabbi Judah says: they were acting [in
>   accordance with] the will of the Sages.

So you see clearly that the harvest started before the omer was brought  against the will of the Sages.

Bartenura brings that the halacha is like Rabbi Judah.

It is stated clearly [here](http://kabbalistnyc.com/?p=2450&cpage=1)

> According to the Mishnah in Menahot, by  the time the Omer sacrifice
>   was brought, the markets of Jerusalem were filled with flour and other
>   products made from the new grain. **Clearly people were involved in**
>   **harvesting and preparing these products before they could be eaten.**
>   Rabbi Meir says that this was done against the wishes of the Sages;
>   Rabbi Yehuda said no objection was raised.

My conclusion is that in practice harvest started before the omer was brought and before the Yom Honaif. Therefore the Yom Honaif is not the beginning of the harvest.

Comment: In Rabbinic literature the day is called יום הנף

Comment: @DoubleAA please source, for my online reading, יום הנף

Comment: @Avrohom-Yitzchok, can you source your answer by using any of the rabbinic comments at https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.30a?lang=bi ? Especially in the light of your answer, "So it is not a day and the Rabbis have nothing to say about it as a day."

Comment: @Avrohom_Yitzchok, the very source you mentioned Mishna_Menochos_10(3), calls Reishit Ketzir as יום הנף and therefore, how can you claim in your answer, "Reishis Ketzir is not a day and the Rabbis have nothing to say about it as a day"?

Comment: @ninamag Forgive me. I understood your question to ask about the term in the quoted possuk “Reishis Ketzir”. I thought you assumed that the term in the possuk referred to a day. I stand by my view that it does not. See the additions you inspired in my answer.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok If you do not consider "Reishis Ketzir" as a day, then why did the rabbis refer to it as "the day of waving" or יום הנף?

Comment: see the additions to my answer.

Comment: reshis ketzir and yom honaif occurs on the same 24-hour period.

Comment: reshis ketzir occurs on the night of nisan 16 and yomhonaif occurs on the morning of nisan 16. by afternoon of nisan 16, the markets are full of harvest. all on the same day.

Comment: @nimang reishis ketzir is a bundle of grain not a time period.

Comment: @DoubleAA "reishis ketzir" comes from vayikra 23:10 and it means "beginning of ... reaping" as per rashi and others.

Comment: @nimang I know that. The first bundle is called "the beginning of the reaping".

Comment: @DoubleAA you "know that" "reishis ketzir" both mean "beginning of ... reaping" as well as a "bundle of grain"? If so, it does also mean a time period ("the beginning of ... reaping").

Comment: @nimang not as well as. It has only one meaning.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok from Mishnah_Menachot.10, it says reshis ketzir occurs best on the night of nisan 16 and yomhonaif occurs on the morning of nisan 16. by afternoon of nisan 16, the markets are full of harvest. all on the same day.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Please correct me: is it not written in Menachot.10 (for example) that ראשית קציר (Leviticus 23:10) was reaped by just one person on shabbat ("אֶחָד בְּשַׁבָּת וְאֶחָד בְּחֹל" Menachot.10), best occuring on the NIGHT of Nisan 16 ("מִצְוָתוֹ לִקְצֹר בַּלַּיְלָה" Menachot.10) and יום הנף took place on the MORNING of Nisan 16; and by AFTERNOON of Nisan 16, the markets are full of harvest ("מִשֶּׁקָּרַב הָעֹמֶר, יוֹצְאִין וּמוֹצְאִין שׁוּק יְרוּשָׁלַיִם שֶׁהוּא מָלֵא קֶמַח וְקָלִי" Menachot.10)?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok This article 

https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8

ראשית הקציר, למחרת יום טוב ראשון של חג הפסח

refers to 
ראשית הקציר

as 
למחרת יום טוב ראשון של חג הפסח